# my Navbar won't show at the top of the screen

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

my nav won't show up at the top of the page, i tried z-index and everything but if i delete transform the bar appears but takes half the screen.

```css
htnl {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  z-index: 300;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

h1,
p {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#welcome-section {
  justify-content: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 160px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 150;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.welcum {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  color: orangered;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <header>
      <h1 class="title">Hey I am Matija</h1>
      <p class="welcum">a web developer</p>
    </header>
  </section>
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>
      <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <section class="project">
    <div class="projects">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="recruit">
    <div class="contact"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Nav wont show up no matter what i do

Comment: You have `<nav class="nav"></nav>`, which is `</nav>` too much. Also, your provided code seems to be missing some parts in the CSS and HTML.

Comment: You have more nav closing tags than opening tags. currently you nav will not contain any other elements because it is immediately closed.

Answer (score 3):

remove `</nav>` after that `<nav class="nav>` and then run the code